# How to get most recent result using Retrofit and Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, retrofit

How can I get the most recent result out of my table on Parse.com?

I'm using the library retrofit.

I have used these:

// Class service

```
public static Service getInstace() {
    if (service == null) {
        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", APPLICATIONID)
                        .addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", RESTAPIKEY)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", TYPE)
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        OkClient okClient = new OkClient(client);
        adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(API).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setClient(okClient).build();
        service = adapter.create(Service.class);
    }
    return service;
}

public static void setClient(OkHttpClient httpClient) {
    client = httpClient;
}


public interface Service {

    //@GET("/classes/WiiData")
    //public void getWiiData(Callback<WiiDataResponse> response);

    @GET("/classes/WiiData/{key}")
    public void getWiiData(@Path("key") String key, Callback<WiiData> response);

    @GET("/classes/list?sort=ASC")
    public void getWiiData(Callback<WiiDataResponse> response);

    @GET("/classes/WiiData")
    public void list(@Query("page") int page, Callback<WiiDataResponse> response);

    @GET("/classes/WiiData/?sort=desc")
    public void getHEAD(@Query("updatedAt") Date date, Callback<WiiDataResponse> response);

    @HEAD("/classes/WiiData")
    public void getHEAD(Callback<WiiData> response);

    @GET("/classes/WiiData")
    public void getLastData(Callback<WiiDataResponse> response);

}
```

Some work... But they can give me a max of 100 results. But these are the first (oldest) 100 results. So the 101 is the newest, and that one I can't get.

Please give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this query: limit=1&order=-updatedAt

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help